# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in rails while using render a action of different controller in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i generate to scaffolds name as header and footers.
In application.html.erb I use this code

```
<%= render template:"headers/index"  %>
<%= yield %>
<%= render template:"headers/index"  %>
```

for render action. this is all because of i want to dynamically customize header and footer layout through html_safe method.

I faced error:

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

I know both why this error comes when render an action in another controller and how to solve. But still facing this error just because of not able to define an action for application.html.erb in application.rb in my applications_controller.rb

```
before_filter :set_headers
def set_headers
  @headers = Header.all
end
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
before_filter :set_headers
def set_headers
 @headers ||= Header.all
end
```

improve you code